# How to set Grid.Background to MediaPlayer in UWP?

Tags: mobile, uwp, windows-phone, uwp-xaml

How to add video to `Grid.Background` in UWP app?

In previous version, I used

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/carosel3.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Comment: What was the previous version and what is the current version? Please update.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how to accomplish this in UWP.

## Composition APIs

The Composition APIs offer `CompositionSurfaceBrush` with which you can paint an area with pixels rendered using a video through `MediaPlayer`. Example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-brushes#paint-with-a-video):

```
Compositor _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(MyGrid).Compositor;
SpriteVisual _videoVisual;
CompositionSurfaceBrush _videoBrush;

// MediaPlayer set up with a create from URI

_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

// Get a source from a URI. This could also be from a file via a picker or a stream
var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("https://www.example.com/video.mp4"));
var item = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);
_mediaPlayer.Source = item;
_mediaPlayer.IsLoopingEnabled = true;

// Get the surface from MediaPlayer and put it on a brush
_videoSurface = _mediaPlayer.GetSurface(_compositor);
_videoBrush = _compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(_videoSurface.CompositionSurface);

_videoVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
_videoVisual.Brush = _videoBrush;
```

Check the docs for more information on look for one of many tutorials on using Composition APIs on the internet (like [here](http://blog.robmikh.com/uwp/composition/2016/05/28/video-shenanigins.html)).

## Separate `MediaPlayer element

A simpler solution would be to just place a `MediaPlayerElement` under the `Grid` itself. When the `Grid` has `Transparent` background, the video will appear below the `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer"
                      AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"
                      Source="ms-appx:///SomeVideo.mp4" />
    <Grid>
       ... your content
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```